# Ошибка SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED

Tags: python, requests

Подскажите как мсправить ошибку, все мозги себе сломал, скоро взорвусь

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tr.calvinklein.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Comment: На английской ветке подробно решают этот вопрос
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests

Comment: Ни одно из решений не помогло. Работают всё ссылки отлично, всё ip, но именно этот tr.calvinklein.com не работает